# GeoJSON data type in PostGIS SQL?

Tags: postgresql, geojson, geometry

I am trying to make a column in a table with data type geoJSON, I have been told that it is the same as the geometry data type, but when I insert a geojson in the field it give me an SQL error. I am using phpgeAdmin. I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is `geometry`, then you need to use [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) like this,

```
INSERT INTO table (col)
VALUES ( ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(JSON) )
```